# lookup data on excel using multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Trying to pull up data using cell references instead of including the criteria in formula as required by =SUMIFS function. Moreover, =VLOOKUP doesn't allow me to include a criteria in the formula as well as look for values to the left of reference.

In the example shown below, I am looking to pull container number and price values of only ALFA and DEN companies.

[image]

Comment: What version of excel do you have?

Comment: Excel 2016 @ScottCraner

Comment: You could also use a Filter (auto or Advanced)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2016 and earlier we need to use INDEX with some form of SMALL.  I like AGGREGATE as it allows the ignoring of errors.

The basic AGGREGATE is:

```
AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$B$7)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$7,{"ALFA","DEN"},0))),ROW($ZZ1)))
```

As it iterates the cells in $B$2:$B$7 it returns an array of row numbers and errors.  The `7` tells the formula to ignore the errors.

`ROW($ZZ1)` is a counter starting at `1` then moving to the next as it is dragged down.  This tells the Aggregate which one in the array to return to the INDEX.

Then we wrap in INDEX:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$B$7)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$7,{"ALFA","DEN"},0))),ROW($ZZ1))),"")
```

Note that the references in the AGGREGATE are specific to the data set and the index is not.  We want to limit the references in the AGGREGATE to limit the number of iterations.

Then we just replace the `A:A` in the index with `C:C` to get the second column.  And drag both formulas down till we get blanks

[image]

---

This is made much easier in Office 365:

```
=FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},A:A,C:C),ISNUMBER(MATCH(B:B,{"ALFA","DEN"},0)))
```

And the results will spill automatically.

Comment: hey Scott, just found out my Ms Office Professional Plus 2019 doesn't have "FILTER" function, any other idea apart from using the aggregate option? Many thanks

Comment: @TeodrosIV No, the other option is to use small in place of aggregate but they are basically the same as we are using aggregate in the small form.